# How do I change my page to display different information based on how the user access it?

Tags: php

I have a page called profiles.php that displays the users own information when logged in. Recently I made it so the user can click on the name of someone else and it will take them to profiles.php. I want it to display the user's they clicked on profile/information, but it only shows your own information.

The way I have the page now is, it uses a session varaible based on if your logged in and from there it puts your data out in its designated places if that makes sense.

//if theuser is logged in then it turns their database id into a variable for later use

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userUid'])){ 
    $current = $_SESSION['Id'];
    }
```

//This is the link a person clicks on thats supposed to take them to that user's page. $post is a varaible from a foreach. I tried to make it so once they click it takes them to profiles.php users id (href = "profiles.php/id"'.$post["idUser"].'")

```
<a href = "profiles.php/id"'.$post["idUser"].'" ><h1>'.$post["UserID"].'</h1></a>
```

I expect the output to be taking the the current user to the desired user's profile page, but the actual output is taking the current user to their own profile page.

Comment: That sometimes happens when you the same variable name for logged in user and the other targeted user.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand you would like to show specific users profile information.

```
// define your connection
require_once('connection.php');
$users = mysql_query($conn, "Select id, name from users);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($users)
?>
 <ul> 
<?php
while($row){

echo <? <a href='profile_display.php?id=<?php $row['id'] ?> > <li> <?php $row['name'] ?> </li></a> ;
}

</ul>


in profile display.php
<?php
require_once'connection.php' ;
$id  = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($id)) {

$result = mysql_query($conn, 'select * from users where id=$id);
if(!empty($result)) {
// display all value here

} else {
echo "No user profile information was found!"
}

?>
```

This code is not tested by me. But I would say this is the strategy needed to be used here.

Pseudocode:

1. List all users
2. User click specific other user, grab their id
3. make a query on db for the user information
4. display if available else display error information

Hope this helps!